# /sites/default/files directory in Drupal when using Git

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-6, migration, synchronization

We are in the process of moving our Drupal 6 sites into Git. I noticed that Drupal 7 actually comes with a default .gitignore file which ignores the settings.php file and the sites/default/files directory. So I am assuming this is standard practice and that I should not version control the files directory. My question is though, what is the best method to move these files through the migration process from dev to test to live then? The live site may contain a ton of images in that directory that people have uploaded on the live site, but then the directory on the DEV server would have new images that some of the developers might have added to content they've created. Currently, when a content editor adds content in the way of a page node for example on the dev site, we have a WYSIWYG editor that allows them to upload an image that ends up in /sites/default/files/images and gets placed in their content. What is the easiest way to sync this files directory between the various servers?

Thanks

Comment: Don't just go with the default, if you consider files important to be under git control, and don't intend to use the same master repository to feed different sites with different stuff in there, by all means adjust `.gitignore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the response to @Brian's answer above, the asker really has two questions:

1. Why shouldn't I include the files directory in source control
2. Does the Deploy module support images uploaded by IMCE

**#1, Reasons why you shouldn't include the files directory in source control:**

- @Brian gives reason #1 above, but it sounds like you do, in fact, push data from dev to prod.
- The files directory isn't well suited to source control. (Rarely do you want to revert or view commit history for the files directory)
- The files directory can grow huge, which might become a repo storage problem
- I usually symlink the files directory outside of the drupal install so I don't need to move it if the server path changes (again, because it can be huge)
- Many of the files in the files directory are likely to be derivatives of other files (in the case of image cache). Even if you were to justify putting the files directory under source control, it doesn't make sense to keep track of `/files/img.png` and `/files/imagecache/small/img.png`.

**#2, Deploy module support for images:**
The short answer is no; Deploy does not support images uploaded by IMCE for D6. See: [Add IMCE image support](http://drupal.org/node/1757760).

But [sarjeet.singh](http://drupal.org/user/200296) provides a [patch for D7](http://drupal.org/files/add-imce-support-1757760-1.patch) in the issue linked to above. Given that the file directory paths are identical on dev/prod, you should be able to adapt it for Drupal 6.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It makes a lot more sense now. I'm gonna keep that directory out of version control and I'm trying the IMCE patch right now. I'll post back my results.

Comment: Actually. I got a little too eager. That patch is most definitely for D7 and I am completely lost trying to adapt it to D6. Arg. The patch is attempting to patch a file that doesn't even exist in the D6 version. I don't mind getting my hands dirty in the code, but unfortunately that one is a little over my head.

Comment: Yeah. Right off the bat it looks like he calls `hook_entity_dependencies` (neither that function nor the concept of entities exist in D6). So now your options are 1) file a request to backport that patch when/if it gets into 7.x; 2) Pay someone to backport it; 3) Adjust your workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't sync your database from development to production, right? So you shouldn't need to sync the files directory either.  The drupal files directory should only be used for content added through the web site.  If your developers are adding resources that are needed in production, then they should be placed somewhere else under version control.

Comment: I guess I was more concerned with content editors who go to the dev server and add a new piece of content. Let's say an About Us page for example that does not exists yet on test or live. In their content is an image which they've uploaded to sites/default/files/images via the IMCE module. Now that image only lives on the dev server. We then use the Deploy module to deploy that About Us page to test and eventually live, but the image referenced in the content would still be stuck on dev. Should I just version control the images directory? Would there be issues doing that?